# Summing a list inside a dictionary Python

Tags: python

I am trying to sum the quantities of the dictionaries in "items"

```
receipt = {
  "tax": .06,
  "items": [
    {
        "food": "grapes",
        "price": 2.50,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "food": "apples",
        "price": 1.99,
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "food": "peach",
        "price": 0.99,
        "quantity": 3
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you wrote and show us your effort for the solution.

Comment: would it be ok to solve it with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `items` and for each `item` get `quantity` and add to `total`:

```
receipt = {
  "tax": .06,
  "items": [
    {
        "food": "grapes",
        "price": 2.50,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "food": "apples",
        "price": 1.99,
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "food": "peach",
        "price": 0.99,
        "quantity": 3
    }

  ]
}
total = 0
for item in receipt["items"]:
     total += item["quantity"]
print(total)
```

Comment: oh my sweet prince (or princess). Thank you so much. I am pretty new to python and this does exactly what I was hoping for. I couldn't figure out how to get to the specific key inside the "items" dictionary. I don't know why that was so difficult.

Comment: @JeffR please do not forget to upvote (arrow) and accept (tick) the answer you liked :)

Answer (score 0):

For price:

```
total = 0
for each in receipt['items']:
    total = total + each['price']
print(total)
```

For quantities:

```
total = 0
for each in receipt['items']:
     total = total + each['quantity']
print(total)
```